# Spotlight button doesn't work (on click displays a sound instead)

Tags: spotlight

It's a totally newbie question, but I started using Mac computers like a month ago and this is something I can't find on the internet. Sometimes (yeah not always and I can't even find out when it happens) when I want to click the spotlight button it displays sound and doesn't work (I use cmd + f instead, but it's pretty confusing). Could you tell me why is it like this?

P.S. The sound sounds like it was disabled or something.

Comment: Welcome, someone will be with you shortly :), we are users like you and have a private life to deal with as well. No paid professionals here, so it might take a while till you get a reply. Meanwhile provide as many details as you can Operating system, computer, including what have you tried so far.

Comment: Spotlight shortcut is cmd+spacebar or whichever is selected in your spotlight settings.

Comment: Wow! It started working. I mean when I pressed cmd + space it opened and then when I closed it the button started working again. Can you explain me this magic?

Comment: It was always there :) using the right shortcut key combination just showed it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok So I have the same problem since a while and I still haven't found any proper solution.

However there is one trick to open it anyway :

### Trick

<kbd></kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> this while able it too.

Comment: Minor nitpick: OS X doesn't use the Apple logo for keyboard shortcuts. It uses the command key symbol (⌘, U+2318) instead.